# Is there a performance difference between data binding and manual assignment in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, data-binding

I have a `label` (in WinForms) in which I want to show a value, which is static (at least at the time). Which is "better" to use: **Data Binding** or **Manual Assigning**? By *better* I mean if there is any difference in performance (or maybe other consequences, which I haven't thought of).

**For example:**

```
// DataBinding method
txtMyTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", viewModel, "myValue");

// Manual assigning method
txtMyTextBox.Text = viewModel.myValue;
```

Comment: Use of `DataBinding` in winforms is generally a bad idea imo.

Comment: DataBinding ALWAYS comes with an overhead, so just use it when you need to.

Comment: I can only suggest you to forget this kind of _micro-optimizations_ unless you have a real problem.

Comment: From a stricly practical point-of-view, it probably won't affect my solution, which method I choose. However, I am a curious person, so the question was mainly to improve my understanding of the subject.

Comment: Have you tried setting up a test application using both methods and experimenting with a performance profiler? Microsoft has introductory pages to profiling Windows applications you may want to look at on both [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx) and [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/beginners-guide-to-performance-profiling).

Comment: @ChristopherKyleHorton No I haven't tried that, but it seems like an interesting experiment, once a get 5 minutes of spare time :-). Thanks for the interesting reading...